# Storing 2 variables at once from a tuple function

Tags: c++, recursion, return, tuples

I have a tuple function that returns a tuple of the form

```
<node*,int>
```

Is there a way to store 2 values at once without creating another tuple. I know we can do

```
n,score=tuplefunct(abc);
```

in python. But if I want to store both return values in c++ without making another tuple i need to call twice

```
n=get<0>(tuplefunct(abc);
score=get<1>(tuplefunct(abc));
```

is there any alternative to this in c++ to store the values at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to call the function twice (note that there is no "another tuple" involved, the function returns one and thats what you use):

```
auto x = tuplefunct(abc);
auto n = get<0>(x);
auto score = get<1>(x);
```

If you have C++17 available you can use [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

```
auto [n,score] = tuplefunct(abc);
```

Or to get close to that without C++17, you can use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) (from C++11 on):

```
node* n;
int score;
std::tie(n,score) = tuplefunct(abc);
```

Comment: I would also mention using `std::tie` as: `node* n; int score; std::tie(n, score) = tuplefunct(abc);`, which does not introduce the auxiliary variable `x` before C++17.

Comment: @DanielLangr I have to admit, I answered merely by reading the documentation, my experience with tuples is rather low, thanks for the tip

Comment: auto should work for my solution. But I am curious about the third solution. Can i use `std::tie(n,-score)` to store score as the negation of returned value?

Comment: @JonBovi interesting question, though `tie` merely creates a tuple of lvalue references that lets you assign to the actual variables. Like everything, it is possible somehow, but afaik not without some additional effort

Comment: @JonBoiv Not with `std::tie`. It creates non-const lvalue references, and you cannot bind a non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue (`-score`).